# Size of Smart Folder

Tags: smart-folders

May be I miss something obvious but could you please give a hint how to check the size of all content of *Smart Folder*?

Answer (score 3):

Select all the files in the smart folder. Then hold down the Option key and do Get Info. That will open a single window summing the data fromall the files instead of one window per file.

Comment: Always consider that smart folder contain links to the actual files, for example say you select all file and as suggested by Patrick Wayne you check the total size. You might get a large number, say 10 Gb. If you check the size of the smart folder itself you might get something as low as a few Kb. That's because all the content actually sits somewhere else and is linked.

Answer (score 2):

Select all the files in the smart folder, hold down the Control key, and right-click to select the "Get Summary Info" option.  It will show you the total size for the selected files.